# Read xml in jenkins

Tags: xml, parsing, jenkins, groovy

```
 def xml = """
<testsuites name="" tests="10" time="20.137">
<script/>
<script/>
<testsuite name="test1" id="3b582d64-0d1a-4016-a482-a02ec2c993c0" timestamp="2021-11-22T12:30:11.253Z" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" time="1.235">
<testcase name="Status code is 200" time="1.235" classname=""/>
<testcase name="validate time response" time="1.235" classname=""/>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
"""

def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
```

Hello, I need to read the information from the xml I found a way to parse it but I can't read the data below

I need to read the time of the testcase

Anyone who can guide me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

rootNode.testsuite.each{tsuite->
  println "suite name = ${tsuite.@name}; time = ${tsuite.@time}"
  tsuite.testcase.each{tcase->
    println "  case name = ${tcase.@name}; time = ${tcase.@time}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Working, thank you very much